# How can I compute total time of an excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to compute the total time in which a system was down, and it looks like using the **SUM(C1:C20298)** it's not working for me, it's giving me some results that are not accurate...
The data looks like this and the cells are formatted as time:

[image]

How can I calculate the total time when the system is down?
I have a lot of data and those timestamps are random , first you have 17:27:22.432, then after a few lines, you have 08:04:25.542

Comment: "it's giving me some results that are not accurate", how inaccurate? Sum should work just fine. What is the real issue?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio it's not fine, if I have 17:15+17:15, it'll give to me: 34:30, not the total time

Comment: What should the total then be based on the example you have just given? What should the total be for example based on the first five cells on the image you posted?

Comment: The total should be: 0 hours, 0 min, 13 sec

Comment: Sort the cells, then substract the first cell from the last. For example: `=A15-A1`. The result should be the total time.

Comment: Tried this, it didn't worked... :(

Comment: If you sort the cells, why will it be wrong? Have you provided enough information with your question? Based on what you have mentioned on the comments, some details are missing.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio sorted them, but if I substract last - first, it'll only make the last - first, not take all into account...

Comment: last - first does take all into account.

Comment: Please label your data to provide clarity. You say timestamps...of what? All up times? All down times, up and down times? Is this over days? We can't read your mind.

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: @RobinsonChera  ,,, the generic formula to get the Total Time is the SUM ,,, but as U have written that Time are in Random order,,,, so first SORT the TIME in column and then procced ,,,,, one question in the TIME ,,,,,only SECONDS are in Decimal and and doesn't match with rest of the FORMAT is `HH:MM` !!  Your TIME are in `hh:mm:ss.00` format ,,,,, better apply `HH"MM"SS AM/PM` and the use the SUM ☺

Answer (score 0):

What the heck, might as well take a stab.

The only way the claim about expected results could seem to apply to the data example is if the odd lines are when a system started up and the even lines when it went down, OR the reverse, with the former seeming more likely.

So I'll answer with that in mind.

Since the data seemed paired, but in possibly diametrically opposite ways, I'll give a formula for finding the difference between each odd/even pair. That can then be used with the `last - first` calculation, appropriately for whichever of the two ways is the actual case:

```
=SUM(  INDEX(A1:A10,SEQUENCE(5,1,2,2),1)  -  INDEX(A1:A10,SEQUENCE(5,1,1,2),1)  )
```

The first `INDEX` outputs all the even rows as it starts with row 2 and increments by 2. The second `INDEX` outputs all the odd rows as it starts with row 1 and increments by 2.

Excel uses its array capabilities to do the pairwise subtractions and `SUM` totals the results.

I used a 10 row input, single column. One would adjust it for the true data reference, and one could "get slick" by using `COUNT` dividing by two to get the number of values the two `SEQUENCE` functions produce.